# Blender is running terribly!

Tags: versions

I like Blender and I had some experience with Blender. I updated to the newest version of 2.76. And now when I launch it, it works fine for a few seconds maybe a minute. Then it starts go in into "Not Responding" mode and back to normal. All this happens in a matter of a second and repeats until I close Blender. This is very annoying, I can't do anything about it. I tried adjusting settings but nothing helps. I don't want to switch to something else like Cinema. Please tell me if you have a similar problem or if know a solution. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: Please give us a little more information about your setup, especially your operating system and anything that might be unusual about your computer or how you installed Blender.

Comment: I havent downloaded blender 2.76 yet but maybe the problem is your pc, it might also depend if you installed it in 64 or 32 bit (which i dont think it is, blender doesnt require a lot of things to run) but for now you could uninstall blender 2.76 and install bleder 2.75 (which i have and havent found any bugs in yet) and you could update a next month when they fix some bugs. Hope this helped.

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can just switch back to Blender 2.75. There's no need to switch to an unfamiliar program if you're already familiar with Blender.

Comment: As per the usual suggestions, have you updated your video drivers and grabbed all your OS updates? After that, try removing your prefs. Other than that, I'm not sure; I'd need to know more about your hardware.

Comment: Try going to **File > Load Factory Settings** and see if that solves it. Could be that one of the plugins you have installed is not compatible with 2.76, so loading factory settings will put all your settings back in their default state (temporarily). If you think the problem can be reproduced by others then consider [filing a bug report](https://developer.blender.org/) including your system specs.

Comment: Make sure your system meets the minimum requirements, and that other processes are not taking too many resources

Comment: I installed 2.75a. Its a little better, doesn't happen as much. Now I know its a problem with The computer. Thanks.